# Example shows that entropy is not upper semi continuous

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

Let $(X, \beta, \mu)$ be probabilty space of compact space $X$. Let $T:X \rightarrow X$ be continuous function, and expansive. It is well known that entropy $\mu \mapsto h_{\mu}$ is upper semi continuous.

$$Question$$

> Can one gives an example that entropy is not upper semi continuous under above condition such that $X$ is not compact?